# Mongodb query result is empty despite there is a field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, get

I'm writing a get method and it always returns an empty result despite the fact the field already exists:

```
router.get('/gettdata/', (req, res, next) => {
  o_id = new ObjectId(req.param.imei),
  Post.find( { imei: { name:"bokhhjbr"} })
  .then((posts) => {
    res.json(posts);
    console.log(posts);
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
});
```

Here is my database:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5eb7f90fb88d8d4d94184333"),
  "imei" : {
    "name" : "bokhhjbr",
    "modele" : "5486"
  },
  "__v" : 0
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5eb7fb9cb88d8d4d94184334"),
  "imei" : {
    "name" : "865566048694354",
    "modele" : "CPH1803"
  },
  "__v" : 0
}
```

I need some help and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Post.find( {"imei.name":"bokhhjbr"})
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#specify-equality-match-on-a-nested-field